# При получении факса Asterisk 13 падает

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

res_fax.so          res_fax_spandsp.so  подключены

sip.conf:

```
callevents=yes
allowtransfer=yes
disallow=all
allow=g729
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
bindport=5060    
canreinvite=no
defaultexpirey=120
dtmfmode=rfc2833
t38pt_udptl=yes,redundancy,maxdatagram=400
faxdetect=yes
echocancel=yes
```

extensions.conf

```
exten => _0XXX.,1,NoOp(================outgoing fax ==============)
exten => _0XXX.,n,Set(FAXOPT(ecm)=yes)
exten => _0XXX.,n,Set(FAXOPT(minrate)=2400)
exten => _0XXX.,n,Set(FAXFILE=/opt/fax/out/${UNIQUEID:0:10}_${CALLERID (num)}.tif)
exten => _0XXX.,n,NoOp(Callerid:${CALLERID}=========EXTEN:${EXTEN})
exten => _0XXX.,n,RecieveFax(${FAXFILE},d)
exten => _0XXX.,n,system(/bin/bash /opt/fax/make_fax.sh ${EXTEN:1} ${FAXFILE})
exten => _0XXX.,n,Hangup()
```

Просто так факс не посылается (Т.38 провайдер поддерживает). 
Начал изобретать костыли (все равно нужно будет).
Суть в том, что когда мы посылаем кому-то факс, набираем номер через 0 и факс принимает астериск.
На строчке exten => fax,n,RecieveFax(${FAXFILE},d) астериск начинает принимать факс, некоторое время принимает, после чего падает. В логах пусто (asterisk clearly ending), тиф-файла не создается.

Факс физически подключен к granstream gwx 4216, который находится в одной сети с астером.

Куда копать?

Comment: Даже в системных логах ничего нет? Попробуйте при включенном дебаге посмотреть, что происходит (`core set debug 9` в консоли asterisk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте у факсового пира убрать g729, т.к. этот кодек не позволяет отправлять/принимать факсы из-за узкой полосы.
Так же неплохо было бы глянуть sip set debug peer FAX_PEER в момент установки соединения.

И последнее. Spandsp не всегда корректно принимает/отправляет факсы. Они просто не проходят. Я рекомендовал бы использовать связку iaxmodem + hylafax + avantfax(опционально). В последствии избавите себя от массы проблем с непроходящими факсами.

Comment: действительно, стоило только создать отдельно пир с disallow=all,
allow=alaw, сразу все заработало.